# I have a dictionary defined with multiple keys and the value for each key is a dictionary himself, how can I sort using values?

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

The results of my program is like this:

```
{'Team1': {'GIOCATE': 4, 'PUNTI': 6, 'Q': 0.9, 'PF': 63, 'PS': 70}, 
 'Team2': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 7, 'Q': 1.1, 'PF': 44, 'PS': 40}, 
 'Team3': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 9, 'Q': 1.514, 'PF': 53, 'PS': 35}
}
```

I want to sort the output like a standing using "PF", the more u have the upper u are in the standing, if "PF" is equals for multiple teams (i cancelled some teams in the example), the more criteria becomes "Q" (the more the upper).
I'm new to python, can someone help me please?

The results should be like that

```
Team7                      4    10    1.07     64    60
Team2                      3     9    1.51     53    35
Team1                      3     9    1.09     50    46
Team4                      4     8   0.935     58    62
Team5                      3     7     1.1     44    40
Team3                      3     7     1.0     44    44
Team8                      4     7   0.955     64    67
Team6                      4     6   0.964     54    56
```

Comment: Set `d = dictionary`, then use `pd.DataFrame(d).T.sort_values(["PF", "Q"], ascending=False)`.  This will sort first on PF then Q, in descending order.

Comment: `dictionary.items().sorted(key = lambda item: (item[1]['PF'], item[1]['Q']))`

Comment: @Barmar, this should be `sorted(dictionary.items(), key=...)` I think?

Comment: Yeah. I originally wrote `.sort()` then realized it was an iterator and I need to use `sorted()`, but didn't fix it properly

Answer (score 2):

Without using pandas or dataframes, `sorted` makes this type of thing very simple if you specify the right key. The `dict.items` function will give you an iterator over tuples of each key and value. That iterator can be passed to `sorted` to generate a sorted list.

```
>>> d = {
...   'Team1': {'GIOCATE': 4, 'PUNTI': 6, 'Q': 0.9, 'PF': 63, 'PS': 70}, 
...   'Team2': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 7, 'Q': 1.1, 'PF': 44, 'PS': 40}, 
...   'Team3': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 9, 'Q': 1.514, 'PF': 53, 'PS': 35}
... }
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['PF'])
[('Team2', {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 7, 'Q': 1.1, 'PF': 44, 'PS': 40}), 
 ('Team3', {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 9, 'Q': 1.514, 'PF': 53, 'PS': 35}), 
 ('Team1', {'GIOCATE': 4, 'PUNTI': 6, 'Q': 0.9, 'PF': 63, 'PS': 70})]
>>> [a for a, _ in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['PF'])]
['Team2', 'Team3', 'Team1']
```

The above sorts purely based on the `'PF'` key, but if we want to sort on `'Q'` if those are equal, we can create a tuple of the two values and sort based on that key.

This approach can be extended to sort on any number of fields in order. If you wished to sort on a field in descending order, you need only negate it. E.g. `key=lambda x: (x[1]['PF'], -x[1]['Q'])`.

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]['PF'], x[1]['Q'])))
[('Team2', {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 7, 'Q': 1.1, 'PF': 44, 'PS': 40}), 
 ('Team3', {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 9, 'Q': 1.514, 'PF': 53, 'PS': 35}), 
 ('Team1', {'GIOCATE': 4, 'PUNTI': 6, 'Q': 0.9, 'PF': 63, 'PS': 70})]
```

We can, if we wish, convert that back to a dictionary. *Note that only from version 3.6 onward do standard Python dictionaries retain insertion order.*

```
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1]['PF'], x[1]['Q'])))
{'Team2': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 7, 'Q': 1.1, 'PF': 44, 'PS': 40}, 
 'Team3': {'GIOCATE': 3, 'PUNTI': 9, 'Q': 1.514, 'PF': 53, 'PS': 35}, 
 'Team1': {'GIOCATE': 4, 'PUNTI': 6, 'Q': 0.9, 'PF': 63, 'PS': 70}}
```